# OpenCV 3.0 x64 VS2013 error LNK1104

Tags: opencv

read already some other threads about these..tried so far everything...
nothing worked. double checked everything.

using x64 system, VS13(x32) and x64 as target system (though i tried using x32 before and had
 the same error)
anyways here are my links:

Debug x64

VC++ exec directory: K:\A_A_Programmierung\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin;$(ExecutablePath)

VC++ lib:       K:\A_A_Programmierung\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;$(LibraryPath)

C/C++:          K:\A_A_Programmierung\opencv\build\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Linker: Target Computer: MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64)

additional dependencies:

opencv_calib3d300d.lib;opencv_core300d.lib;opencv_features2d300d.lib;opencv_flann300d.lib;opencv_highgui300d.lib;opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib;opencv_imgproc300d.lib;opencv_ml300d.lib;opencv_objdetect300d.lib;opencv_photo300d.lib;opencv_shape300d.lib;opencv_stitching300d.lib;opencv_superres300d.lib;opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_video300d.lib;opencv_videoio300d.lib;opencv_videostab300d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Additional lib. directory:

K:\A_A_Programmierung\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

also checked some other settings mentioned in other threads!
and did set the enviroment variable as mentioned in a tut and also ran VS13 as admin

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok fixed it myself...
you have to add the files of opencv 3.0 under opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib
for the linker input. (see additional dependencies) which isnt the whole list anymore...
list on the official tutorial is not up to date!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(OPENCV_DIR)\staticlib` instead of `$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib`.