# OpenCV doesn't work with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I just installed openCV ver. 3.00 beta on my computer and I'm trying to test it with VS2013. I followed quick start guide:

1) [Installation for windows](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html), using pre-build libraries.

2) [OpenCV inside Microsoft VS](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to), using local method and `x64/vc12` directory for libraries.

As a result, their example(listed in link #2) produced an error:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << " Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if (image.empty()) // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // Create a window for display.
    imshow("Display window", image); // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test_openCV, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d300d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

As far as I understand, my program can see openCV libraries, but for some reason cannot open them. Please help.

Thanks

Update: Tried to do what was recommended in first four comments, no result still. So I will post here full information:

Project: CUDA 6.5 (I need to work with CUDA).

Source file: `Source.cpp`

Mode: Debug, x64.

Enviromental variables:

```
OPENCV_DIR: C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12

Path (the last string): %OPENCV_DIR%\bin
```

Page Properties:

```
C\C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories(last string):
    $(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include
Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories(last string):
    $(OPENCV_DIR)\lib
Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:
    opencv_calib3d300d.lib
    opencv_core300d.lib
    opencv_features2d300d.lib
    opencv_flann300d.lib
    opencv_highgui300d.lib
    opencv_imgcodecs300d.lib
    opencv_imgproc300d.lib
    opencv_ml300d.lib
    opencv_objdetect300d.lib
    opencv_photo300d.lib
    opencv_shape300d.lib
    opencv_stitching300d.lib
    opencv_superres300d.lib
    opencv_ts300d.lib
    opencv_video300d.lib
    opencv_videoio300d.lib
    opencv_videostab300d.lib
```

Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test_openCV, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d300d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So, I cannot build x64 project for some reason. Error is the same.

Update 2: **If you can build this example (or any example with OpenCV), can you please send it on genkin@physics.msu.ru? I will figure it out by myself**

Comment: Have you read this? http://answers.opencv.org/question/51060/error-lnk1181-opencv_calib3d300dlib/

Comment: Another Question (Answered) on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066754/opencv-3-0-x64-vs2013-error-lnk1104

Comment: Still didn't figured out what should I do, sorry

Comment: `x64/vc12` libraries are for 64 bit applications and Visual Studio 2013. You can not use the x64 libraries for the Win32 configuration. You will need the 32 bit versions for that. Build a x64 application or switch to 32 bit libraries.

Comment: Still not working. I posted an update with full information

Comment: Does `opencv_calib3d300d.lib` exist in this folder `C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12`

Comment: Oh, that might be the issue. All this libraries are in the folder `C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib`

Comment: I tried to include the last path into linker -> general. As a result, a huge amount of errors of the type `Unresolved external symbol` and `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Source.obj`

Comment: Oh I am sorry you have `C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib` as the search path not `C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12`

Comment: That means your runtime settings for your application conflict from the settings for the compiled opencv. I believe you need to set the runtime for your application to Multithreaded debug /MTd not Multithreaded Debug DLL /MDd

Comment: I did it (in C\C++ -> code generation), and (with `C:\programs\misha\opencv\build\x64\vc12\staticlib` included in linker) there are 580 errors instead of 682.

Comment: @drescherjm, can you send any helloword open_CV project by mail?

Comment: Since I would have to generate one ( giving you 30+ minutes of my time) I have no time for that. I am under a very important deadline at work.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But why 30 minutes? If u used it before, you can set everything up for 1 minute and build it for 15 sec, and send it as zip for another 30sec

Comment: So everyone is using openCV in the same regime and it is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long time of different attempts, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491041/opencv-unresolved-external-symbol). For `x64` project, in addition to what I did above, you have to:

1) Restart your PC after setting enviromental variables. Variable Path was not updated on my computer without restart.

2) In addition to libraries added above, you have to add (although, for this example some of them might not be used):

```
ippicvmt.lib
IlmImfd.lib
libtiffd.lib 
libpngd.lib
libjasperd.lib
libjpegd.lib
libwebpd.lib
zlibd.lib
comctl32.lib
```

Edit: I recently had to install it again on a new PC. As user1060873 pointed out, you have to add only the libraries located in your $OPENCV$/lib folder. For example, on my PC it is `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib`. Note, that for debug mode you should add `opencv_world310d.lib`, and for release `opencv_world310.lib`

Comment: Can I ask where the `opencv_core300d.lib` and other are files located? If you remember.

Comment: There seems to be an update to how things are done... http://stackoverflow.com/a/30608745/5184092 sort of worked minus `opencv_ts300d.lib`. I am on version `320` and used that instead of `300` now getting a `dll` error that I have to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that solution did not work for me.

I made it work by adding as additional dependencies(Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:) only those libraries located in my $(OPENCV_DIR)\lib folder. Namely: opencv_ts300d.lib;opencv_world300d.lib.

Comment: You should probably explain *which* solution didn't work, since you can't assume any particular order of answers or even that the other answer will remain. A bit of code formatting (Ctrl-K) would not go amiss either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same problem. I am using win7 x64 with VS2015 and OpenCV 3.2
After several hours of struggling I finally found out the answer. Each version is not the same, and there may be some differences. So this is what I did :

1. Find where your libraries are for Additional Library, it is located on        `$OPENCV$/lib` folder
2. ONLY put those is `$OPENCV$/lib` folder into the Additional Library (`Project properties, Configuration Properties, Linker, Input`). In my case I put `opencv_world300d.lib` (**according to official tutorial which is not up to date!**) into my Additional Library. But after I check the library folder, there is `opencv_world320d.lib`, so instead of 300 I write 320.

Comment: That was what I did wrong too. also check the inheritance values and remove 'opencv_world320d.lib' at my case

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem by unchecking the "inherit from parent or project defaults" checkbox under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

I added "opencv_world300d.lib" since Im using opencv 3.0.0 build x64 vc11

Answer (score 0):

I need do following FIVE things to configure OpenCV well for Microsoft Visual Studio on Windows.

Denote the root of OpenCV folder as `OpenCV_ROOT`, which evaluates as `/path/to/OpenCV` that contains `OpenCVConfig.cmake`. Let's start with opening the project properties in the menubar `Project → ProjectName`

[image]

1. Add OpenCV's header files, I.e. `${OpenCV_ROOT}/include`, to project Include Directories.

[image]

2. Add OpenCV's lib files, I.e. `${OpenCV_ROOT}/x64/vc16/lib`, to project Library Directories.

[image]

3. Add all OpenCV's lib files under `${OpenCV_ROOT}/x64/vc16/lib` to project Additional Dependencies.

[image]

On Windows, you can use `ls *.lib | select name` in PowerShell to list only file names under a directory.

4. Make sure above configuration changes match the selected configuration in your project. If you select `Release` configuration and `x64` platform in the project, then you need apply above changes in `Release` configuration and `x64` platform.

[image]

5. Add OpenCV's `bin` directory, I.e. `${OpenCV_ROOT}/x64/vc16/bin`, to Windows Environment Path. You may need reopen the Visual Studio if you didn't set OpenCV's `bin` Path before.

NOTE: Although there is an official guide [OpenCV: How to build applications with OpenCV inside the 'Microsoft Visual Studio'](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html) to explain how to build an application with OpenCV, it still lacks some details like step 4 and step 5 in my provided steps.